# Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid X: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, centos-7

I'm not sure what exactly causing, but I'm getting following error:

```
Apr 11 12:30:00 X alacarte-made-2.desktop: [1712:1735:0411/123000:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(162)] Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid 2897: Permission denied
```

after upgrading to latest beta version (51), I now get this:

```
Apr 25 16:44:24 wcmisdlin02 alacarte-made-2.desktop: [20853:20853:0425/164424:ERROR:background_mode_manager_aura.cc(13)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BackgroundModeManager::EnableLaunchOnStartup(bool)
Apr 25 16:44:24 wcmisdlin02 gnome-session: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2400001 (New Tab - )
Apr 25 16:44:24 wcmisdlin02 alacarte-made-2.desktop: [20853:20853:0425/164424:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'hiding' of undefined
Apr 25 16:44:24 wcmisdlin02 alacarte-made-2.desktop: at Object.handleHiding (chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/adblock_start_chrome.js:103:13)
Apr 25 16:44:24 wcmisdlin02 alacarte-made-2.desktop: at chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/adblock_start_common.js:203:12", source: https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8 (0)
Apr 25 16:44:24 wcmisdlin02 alacarte-made-2.desktop: [20853:20853:0425/164424:ERROR:display_info_provider_aura.cc(31)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::DisplayInfoProviderAura::UpdateDisplayUnitInfoForPlatform(const gfx::Display &, extensions::api::system_display::DisplayUnitInfo *)
Apr 25 16:44:25 wcmisdlin02 alacarte-made-2.desktop: [20853:20853:0425/164425:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/n/gcosuc. The request was redirected to a URL ('about:blank') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.", source: https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8 (0)
Apr 25 16:48:39 wcmisdlin02 alacarte-made-2.desktop: [310:310:0425/164839:ERROR:PlatformKeyboardEvent.cpp(117)] Not implemented reached in static PlatformEvent::Modifiers blink::PlatformKeyboardEvent::getCurrentModifierState()
```

My system:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux X 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 31 16:04:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ rpm -q google-chrome-beta
google-chrome-beta-51.0.2704.22-1.x86_64
$
```

How does one address this issue?

Comment: I am running into the same thing. Seems to be a known issue. Might be worth monitoring this thread. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576409